# Curl not getting an xml response with https url?

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, simplexml

I am working with Expedia's api and I am trying to do a test booking. I have to call a https url. I have been able to make connections to all other normal http request, but now I am stuck. Here is how I am calling the page. all the php values from my form are correct but I get nothing in the xml file..I mean nothing no errors, nothing! I am truly stuck and do not know what to do. Here is my php code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
$fp = fopen('bookit.xml','w'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/res?cid=55505&minorRev=13&apiKey=4sr8d8bsn75tpcuja6ypx5g3&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&customerIpAddress=10.184.2.9&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/535.11+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/17.0.963.79+Safari/535.11&customerSessionId=&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=<HotelRoomReservationRequest><hotelId>".$hid."</hotelId><arrivalDate>".$arrive."</arrivalDate><departureDate>".$depart."</departureDate><supplierType>".$supplier."</supplierType><rateKey>".$rkey."</rateKey><rateCode>".$ratecode."</rateCode><roomTypeCode>".$roomcode."</roomTypeCode><chargeableRate>".$total."</chargeableRate><RoomGroup><Room><numberOfAdults>".$adults."</numberOfAdults><numberOfChildren>".$children."</numberOfChildren><childAges>".$childages."</childAges><firstName>".$fname."</firstName><lastName>".$lname."</lastName><smokingPreference>".$smoking."</smokingPreference></Room></RoomGroup><ReservationInfo><email>".$email."</email><firstName>".$ccname."</firstName><lastName>".$cclast."</lastName><homePhone>".$phone."</homePhone><workPhone></workPhone><creditCardType>".$cc."</creditCardType><creditCardNumber>".$ccnumber."</creditCardNumber><creditCardExpirationMonth>".$exmonth."</creditCardExpirationMonth><creditCardExpirationYear>".$exyear."</creditCardExpirationYear><creditCardIdentifier>".$ccsecure."</creditCardIdentifier></ReservationInfo><AddressInfo><address1>".$street1."</address1><city>".$city."</city><stateProvinceCode>AZ</stateProvinceCode><countryCode>".$country."</countryCode><postalCode>".$zip."</postalCode></AddressInfo></HotelRoomReservationRequest>");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");  
$val = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);//Close curl session 
fclose($fp); //Close file overwrite 
var_dump($val);
$data = simplexml_load_file('bookit.xml');
```

And I like I said I get nothing at all. I have checked all the code and I do not see a problem and the url is correct.. any help would be so greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);`

Comment: I tried this and in the var_dump($val) instead of returning string(0)"" it returned bool(true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customer IP addr is `10.184.2.9`, you say? I'm skeptical of that.

Immediately after the `curl_exec`, but before you close `$ch`, echo the output of `curl_error($ch)`. Is there anything useful there?

Comment: nope... tried it and I set the IP address to echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']... made no difference.. grr, I am so confused. Here is the test booking page: https://www.travellinginmexico.com/test/payment_request.php?hid=204919&d=04/30/2012&a=04/28/2012&ad=2&ch=0&ag=-?-&r=975025&ro=1 would you mind taking a look, although don't think it will do much good. But when I book this, I have to use specific credit card info for test bookings.